# How to order pre-written String[] array elements alphabetically pre-run-time in IntelliJ-IDEA?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, intellij-idea

I've typed up a bunch of String[] arrays in an interface. I want IntelliJ-IDEA to order the elements alphabetically.

I'm not talking about ordering during run-time or compile-time. I want the actual java/text-file to be modified.

*How can I get IntelliJ-IDEA to sort String[] array elements alphabetically and in the ".java" files themselves?*

**Current Status:**

```
String[] RACES = {
  "human", "elf", "small folk", "orc", "goblin", "aasimar", "tiefling"};
```

**Desired Status:**

```
String[] RACES = {
  "aasimar", "elf",  "goblin", "human", "orc", "small folk", "tiefling"};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Position the text cursor inside the array. Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and choose `Sort content`. This functionality is available to IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1, and later versions.